# Java.lang.NullpointerException Attempt to invoke virtual method void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.setAdapter)

Tags: java, android

I have been trying all day to understand the mistake. I an a learner and was trying a custom adapter and custom object class for the first time. Please help me understand my mistakes. I have tried a lot of surfing until finally entering my doubt in here. Any little help will be appreciated. I have tried this after learning from a website. I followed the same steps but am unable to resolve this. The logcat says

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.miwok, PID: 7814
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.miwok/com.example.miwok.NumbersActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2487)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2547)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1398)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5603)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.miwok.NumbersActivity.onCreate(NumbersActivity.java:30)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6355)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2440)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2547) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:151) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1398) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5603) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652) package com.example.miwok;
```

Here is the NumbersActivity

```
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class NumbersActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.intial);
        ArrayList<Word>words1=new ArrayList<Word>();
        words1.add(new Word("One","lutti"));
        words1.add(new Word("Two","ottiko"));
        words1.add(new Word("Three","tolookosu"));
        words1.add(new Word("Four","oyyisa"));
        words1.add(new Word("Five","massokka"));
        words1.add(new Word("Six","temmokka"));
        words1.add(new Word("seven","kenukaku"));
        words1.add(new Word("Eight","kawinta"));
        words1.add(new Word("Nine","wo'e"));
        words1.add(new Word("Ten","na'aacha"));
        WordAdapter itemsAdapter=new WordAdapter(this, words1);
        ListView listview=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.word_list);
        listview.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);

    }
}
```

The WordAdapter is here

```
package com.example.miwok;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class WordAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Word> {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = WordAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
    public WordAdapter(Activity context,ArrayList<Word> words){

        super(context,0,words);
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @NonNull View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View listItemview=convertView;
        if(listItemview==null)
        {
            listItemview=LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);
        }
        Word current=getItem(position);
        TextView txt=(TextView)listItemview.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        txt.setText(current.getDefaultTranslation());
        TextView txt1=(TextView)listItemview.findViewById(R.id.miwok_translation);
        txt1.setText(current.getMiwokTranslation());
        return listItemview;
    }
    }
```

Here is the word java file

```
package com.example.miwok;

public class Word {
    private String mMiwokTranslation;
    private String mDefaultTranslation;

    public Word(String vDefaultTranslation, String vMiwokTranslation) {
        mMiwokTranslation = vMiwokTranslation;
        mDefaultTranslation = vDefaultTranslation;
    }

    public String getDefaultTranslation() {
        return mDefaultTranslation;
    }
    public String getMiwokTranslation() {
        return mMiwokTranslation;
    }
}
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `NullPointerException` indicates that you're trying to access a non existing thing.

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'void
>   android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a
>   null object reference
>       at com.example.miwok.NumbersActivity.onCreate(NumbersActivity.java:30)

You haven't retrieve the ListView. Are you sure you're using the right xml file ? Is it the correct ID ?

Comment: Then what should I do now?